# failed to load HTTP resource Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: 1: failed to load HTTP resource

Tags: r, http, web-scraping, dplyr

I was writing program in R for web scraping but got an error. Below is my code

```
comp <- c("Microsoft", "Apple", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook",
             "Twitter", "IBM", "Yahoo", "Netflix")

sym <- c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN", "FB", "TWTR", "IBM", "YHOO", "NFLX")

dow_art <- function(symbol) {
  WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource(paste0("NASDAQ:", symbol)))}

stock_articles <- data.frame(company = comp,symbol = sym) %>%
  mutate(cor = map(symbol, dow_art))
```

I am getting an error as:

> "failed to load HTTP resource Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
> Evaluation error: 1: failed to load HTTP resource"

I have added the following libraries:

```
library(magrittr)
(purrr)
(dplyr)
(tidyr)
(httr)
(XML)
(tm)
(tm.plugin.webmining)
```

Please help me in rectifying the error.

Thanks in advance.